# How to copy a vector of lists?

Tags: c++, oop, data-structures, vector, copy

In my program I need to copy (or even use) a `private` data structure into the .cpp file of a completely different class.  At the moment I am even having trouble just simply accessing it remotely, it seg faults when I try to print it.  Here is a simplified version of my class with the data structure:

```
class Graph
{
private:
    class Edge
    {
    public:
        Edge(string vertex, int weight)
        {
            m_vertex = vertex;
            m_weight = weight;
        }
        ~Edge(){}
        string m_vertex;
        int m_weight;
    };
    vector< list<Edge> > adjList;
public:
    Graph();
    ~Graph();
    vector < list < Edge > > get_adjList(){return adjList;}
    //Other functions....

};
```

In a completely different function I try to do this...

```
void MinPriority::testPrint(string targetVertex) //FOR TESTING PURPOSES SO FAR (FAILS TO WORK) SEGMENTATION FAULT NO MATTER WHAT
{

    targetVertex = "A";
    Graph graph;
    graph.adjList = graph.get_adjList(); //adjList is our empty container based on the array of linked lists
    /*1*/cout << graph.get_adjList()[0].front().m_vertex << " TEST!" << endl;

    /*2*/cout << "The very first vertex is: ";
    if(graph.adjList.size() == 0)
        cout << "NULL<!>" << endl;
    else cout << graph.adjList[0].front().m_vertex << endl;
}
```

Note i set targetVertex to 'a' so my program compiles since im including -Werror in my makefile (required for assignment).When I comment out `/*1*/` and run down to `/*2*/` the output will always be `"The very first vertex is: NULL<!>"`, no matter how many elements are in the data structure. At `/*1*/` I try to print out the object returned by the function `get_adjList()` but it seg faults reading this:

```
Exception: STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION at eip=611298C5
eax=0A0A0A0A ebx=01010101 ecx=20050884 edx=F5F5F5F5 esi=20058488 edi=20060000
ebp=0028A8D8 esp=0028A8D0 program=C:\cygwin\home\Ryan\311\P5Dec16\Graph.exe, pid 5612, thread main
cs=0023 ds=002B es=002B fs=0053 gs=002B ss=002B
Stack trace:
Frame     Function  Args
0028A8D8  611298C5  (20058400, 0000000A, 20058488, 610FD3CA)
0028A938  6115F91F  (0028D41C, 61187720, 0028A958, 0043455D)
0028A988  61137BF7  (0028D41C, 20058400, 00000001, 20058488)
0028A9B8  61137CD5  (20058400, 00000001, 20058488, 61187720)
0028A9D8  610D6745  (00449240, 20058400, 20058488, 004493C4)
0028AA68  004439BA  (004493C0, 6123D5FC, 004452B4, 0028AAA0)
0028AB08  00402756  (0028AC20, 0028ABB0, 20010100, 004011C1)
0028AC68  00401583  (00000001, 0028AC90, 20010100, 612757A2)
0028ACF8  6100763A  (00000000, 0028CD78, 61006C50, 00000000)
End of stack trace
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Basically in short, I would like to know what this stack trace is (I have had seg faults before but I have never seen this).  I would like to know how to properly access the data structure from class Graph in other files that `#include "Graph.h"`.  I am also unsure how to copy my object inside of `testPrint();`.  Why is it that this works perfectly in `Graph.cpp`?

```
void Graph::set_array(string vertex)
{
    //increment vector size by 1 and insert a new Edge object into the vector of linked lists
    cout << "ADDING " << vertex << " TO VECTOR" << endl;
    adjList.resize(adjList.size() + 1);
    adjList[adjList.size() - 1].push_back(Edge(vertex, 0));
}
```

Comment: What does the default constructor of `Graph` do?

Comment: theres nothing in it `Graph::Graph()
{

}`  the destructor is also empty.

Comment: You should compile with `-g` flag to have debug symbol, so you will have a more understandable backtrace. You may also pass object by 'const reference' (instead of by value) to avoid copy.

Comment: Should get_adjList really be returning an entirely fresh copy, and not a reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Graph graph;
```

As you stated, the default constructor of `Graph` does nothing. So at this point, `graph.adjList` is empty.

```
graph.adjList = graph.get_adjList();
```

This is a pointless statement which assigns to `graph.adjList` from a copy of itself.  Since it was empty before, it is still empty now.

```
cout << graph.get_adjList()[0].front().m_vertex << " TEST!" << endl;
```

This tries to access the first element of (a copy of) `graph.adjList`.  But `graph.adjList` is empty *(i.e. it doesn't have a first element)*, so this is undefined behavior. It may or may not be the cause of your segfault, but it is certainly a problem that must be fixed before any further useful debugging can take place.

Comment: what would the graph structure need to contain?  the vector of lists?

Comment: @user3040019: I'm afraid I don't understand that question, or at least don't have enough information about your problem to have any idea how to answer it.

Comment: sorry i meant what would the graph "constructor" need to contain/

Comment: @user3040019: For that `cout` statement to be valid, it would, at the very least need to put one element (one `list<Edge>`) into `adjList`, perhaps via `push_back`, or `emplace_back` or `resize`.  You also try to access the first element of the list, so it would also need to put at least one element (one `Edge`) into that list you just added.

Comment: I'm going to add checks to make sure if there are no elements in the data structure.  I was thinking about making my constructor something like this: `Graph::Graph()
{
    new vector < list < Edge > >;
}` my thoughts are that this will create a new vector that we can use the reference the vector declared in graph.h.  I'm not too sure if it would work though.

Comment: @user3040019: No. That just allocates a new vector(which has no relation whatsoever to `adjList`) and discards the pointer to it, resulting in a memory leak.  You need to read a C++ book.

Comment: After adding in 3 nodes (A,0) (B,0) and (C,0) It actually did not seg fault this time, but it still sees nothing in the data structure it prints this: `ADDING A TO VECTOR
ADDING B TO VECTOR
ADDING C TO VECTOR
(A, 0) -->
(B, 0) -->
(C, 0) -->
 TEST!
The very first vertex is: NULL<!>`

Comment: Well i am looking around everywhere for a simple vector constructor, but I haven't found anything yet.  The problem is that my teacher expects me to already know all of this (even though we werent supposed to know it in the prerequisite class).

Comment: @user3040019: I supposed that you add edge to a copy of the vector of the graph, using `vector< list < Edge > >& get_adjList() {return adjList;}` (`&` added) may solve some of your problem.